# Using Open Graph with Ajax Overlay

Tags: ajax, facebook-opengraph

Was wondering if anyone has had any experience in implementing Open Graph with the following use case:

Imagine you have a tab application which is delivering content to users.
On this tab application you are delivering a number of promotions in a carousel format.
Each promotion in the carousel has a call to action which loads some content in an overlay.
I'd like to have an open graph action associated with that call to action.
The intention is that when a friend sees the published action, clicking it will take them to the tab application and, via a param in app_data, pop the overlay belonging to the promotion the action relates to.

I have the auto overlay popup already working.

For the Open Graph piece though, as far as I can tell from the documentation, you need to attach your open graph meta data tags to a stand alone document that represents the content (and in fact *is* the content). It would seem from the default behaviour that this page needs to exist in it's own right and could not be an ajax loaded fragment on a page that contains several promotions.

Can anyone add their own experiences in trying to get something more complex than flat pages working with Open Graph? For example, is it possible to have an 'end point' page that the meta data will point to for the purposes of creating the feed story but the user will still be taken to the carousel page when they click the story?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, is it possible to have an 'end point' page that the meta data will point to for the purposes of creating the feed story but the user will still be taken to the carousel page when they click the story?

Sure, just redirect the user from your endpoint to the site you want them to actually see …